# Autoloading broken in latest PayPal PHP SDK

Tags: php, paypal, autoload

With older versions of the [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK), you could simply use

```
require_once(PATHTOCOMPOSERVENDORDIR . '/autoload.php');
```

And then just begin using the SDK like

```
$refundReqest = new RefundTransactionRequestType();
```

Unfortunately, this no longer works and results in errors like

```
Class 'RefundTransactionRequestType' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although annoying, the simple solution is to reference all the necessary dependencies explicitly, e.g.

```
require_once(PATHTOCOMPOSERVENDORDIR . '/autoload.php');
use PayPal\PayPalAPI\RefundTransactionRequestType;
use PayPal\PayPalAPI\RefundTransactionReq;
use PayPal\CoreComponentTypes\BasicAmountType;
use PayPal\Service\PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService;
```

Obviously, your dependencies will probably be different and you can figure them out with trial and error, using the "Class Not Found" errors.

Comment: You might be interested in checking out my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  I've been maintaining it for years now and I (as well as many others using it) prefer it over what PayPal provides.  It works with Composer (optionally) and comes with fully functional samples of nearly every classic API call, which I still prefer over the REST API because it's much more mature.

Comment: The reason why we namespacing is added because if you would have the class name exactly matching with one of PayPal, it would lead to conflicts, that would be really hard to solve.